# Multiple jQuery UIProgress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm trying to display multiple, "static" jQuery Progress Bars on a single page, all with different different values.... Anyhow, say I have this bit of code:

```
$(function() {
$(".progressbar").progressbar({value: 37});
})
```

Is there a way to use the same class for multiple "instances" of the progress bar? And is it possible to pass different values?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multuiple elements which have a class of `progressbar`, the line `$('.progressbar').progressbar()` should make all of them into separate progress bars.

If you give each progressbar element a different ID, you can manipulate them individually.

For example:

```
$('#bar1').progressbar({value: 37});
$('#bar2').progressbar({value: 54});
$('#bar3').progressbar({value: 99});
```

Comment: Yeah... But they will be generated by php based on an undefined number of rows in a db...